# Can list comprehension have a prefix, suffix?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I need to create a list comprehension and add one extra item at the start and end. Is there a better way than just using a helper function to do it?

```
# convert tuple from permutation into a list with predecessor and successor
def perm_to_list(predecessor, perm, successor):
    result = [predecessor]
    result.extend(list(perm))
    result.append(successor)
    return result

candidates = [perm_to_list(prefix, x, suffix) 
              for x in permutations(something)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match the sample code (where you add prefix and suffix to each element of a list comprehension)

```
candidates = [[prefix] + list(x) + [suffix] for x in permutations(something)]
```

To answer the question you actually asked (to add a prefix and suffix to the list comprehension itself)

```
candidates = [prefix] + [somefunction(x) for x in permutations(something)] + [suffix]
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was looking for. (Although speed is the same. They are paths in a travelling salesman problem.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a new [feature](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) available only in Python 3.5:

Unpacking of iterables anywhere in a list:

```
[prefix, *iterable, suffix]
```

(I wish they added it sooner)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative if speed is *critical*, thought I'd offer this approach. You can use a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) which has native support for appending to either the *head* or *tail* of the structure.

It's a double-ended queue data structure, and as such offers ***O(1)*** prepending as opposed to ***O(n)*** for lists.

```
from collections import deque
dq = deque(range(1,10))  # Test list passed to deque -> deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
dq.appendleft(0)
dq.append(10)
print dq
deque([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

Comment: Good point, but I never tried to append to the beginning.  I just started a new list with the prefix, and appended to the end. This isn't the bottleneck, so I'm not worried too much about it's speed, now.